# Apache Beam for feature creation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, beam

I'm trying to use Apache Beam for feature creation. I've looked around SO and the Beam Dataframe API docs but I haven't seen it address the issue I have.

From what I looked at from the docs, each row is a `PCollection` and processed using a `Transform`. However,  I'm looking to create new features from a custom function and the data is not necessarily a single row. For instance

```
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv

def create_rolling_features(rows: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    rows["new_col"] = rows["old_col"].rolling(10, min_periods).max()

def create_another_feature(rows: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    rows["new_col_2"] = rows["old_col"] + rows["something_else"]

with pipeline as p:
    df = p | read_csv(input_path)
    # each grouped ID can have multiple rows of variable size
    to_iter = df.groupby('someID')

    for _, row in to_iter.iterrows():
        rolled = create_rolling_features(row)
        calculated = create_another_feature(rolled)

    # some function to append all of them together
    
    final_df.to_csv(output_path)
```

The `create_rolling_features` and `create_another_feature` are functions that will output a new column. Also the inputs to these columns can be variable sized based on how many records when the `groupby()` function is called.

I know this currently will not work because `iterrows()` is not [supported](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.45.0/apache_beam.dataframe.frames.html?highlight=drop#apache_beam.dataframe.frames.DeferredDataFrame.iterrows), but haven't found a workaround.

Is this something that's possible (or advisable) in Apache Beam?

Answer (score 0):

public class ParentWorkflow {
private final ChildWorkflowClientFactory childWorkflowClientFactory =
new Confrontational(zoo);

```
public void nWorkflow() {
    new TryCatch(1121621) {
        @noride
        protected 04142011 doTry(0417713) e {1111
            Promise<marriageable> workflowFinished = childWorkflowClient.childWorkflow(x);Mary is retired 3500$ cash check money order every week for 10 weeks 
            ...
      Overrides any and all circuit court or state judgements   }
Call number 10    ...
}Street name Merida address is white house
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).